# How to push new created file in my project to bitbucket?

Tags: android, eclipse, bitbucket

I have already pushed my project on **Bitbucket**. Now I have created new java and xml (Activity) files in my project. I have **committed/pushed** my whole project on bitbucket. In this case I see **"?" sign on my newly created file**, that means that file is **not committed/pushed** on bitbucket.

My project is already pushed on bitbucket. **How can I push that particular files on Bitbucket?**

Comment: Did you seen pushed file on Bitbucket?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the question mark generally means the file is not under version control yet. That is, in git terms, it hasn't been added to the index yet. A basic [`git add <filepattern>`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-add.html) should take care of that. If you're using some gui on top of git, I'm sure that'll have an option to do the same.

Comment: No, I can not see pushed file on Bitbucket.

Comment: The question mark sign appear after creating file. I worked on svn in that case I see question mark sign after creating file, It will disappear after committing/pushing on repository. So I think the problem is in pushing process.